# Regexp to detect call time pass by references in PHP source code

Tags: php, regex, eclipse

I'm looking for a regular expression that will accurately identify any PHP call time pass by references in source code in order to aid migration to PHP 5.3.

Currently, I have `[^=&]\s*&\s*\$`, but this doesn't filter out assignment cases (`$var = &$othervar;`).

This regexp should be compatible with eclipse (sorry, not sure what flavor of regexp eclipse parses).

**Edit:** This one is a little bit closer (although a bit of a hack): `(?<!([&=]\s{0,15}))&\s*\$`

Comment: Well, it's going to be much harder...  Since `array($var)` is valid.  So I'm not sure a regex will even be able to reliably detect it (at least a simple one)...

Comment: And that's why I asked the question ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [phpcs](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) for this. It has a [rule to detect Call Time Pass by References](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/docs/1.2.2/PHP_CodeSniffer/Generic_Sniffs_Functions_CallTimePassByReferenceSniff.html):

> Ensures that variables are not passed by reference when calling a function.

There is also a [plugin to integrate phpcs into Eclipse](http://www.phpsrc.org/projects/pti-php-codesniffer/wiki/)

Generating rulesets for PHPCS (and PMD) is easy with this online generator:

- http://edorian.github.io/php-coding-standard-generator/#phpcs

Comment: Thanks for the link, Gordon, but I'm really looking for a regexp. This codebase has literally hundreds of source files.

Comment: +1: A pre-built solution is best...  @Kenaniah: `phpcs` is a scanner made to scan literally hundreds of source files and output a report of what it found.  So it sounds to me exactly like what you're looking for...

Comment: I'll give it a shot since there's an eclipse plugin for it.

Comment: I don't understand how to tell phpcs to use this rule, could you please elaborate how to use phpcs in this way?

Comment: @ThorSummoner you need to have a ruleset that includes this sniff. See the link I added to the answer. It allows for easy creation of such a ruleset.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, I didn't find any of the calltime pass by reference keywords on that generator :c, did I just miss it?

Comment: @ThorSummoner yes, you did. check again :)

Comment: I also used this this sniff. Although, this does actually not answer the initial question which clearly askes for a regex pattern.

Answer (score 4):

`php -l` (php-linter) finds call-time pass-by-reference errors, I used

```
find -name '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; >/dev/null
```

in linux

Comment: This works if the php binary that you use for the lint check is version 5.4 or greater; I found that a 5.3 lint check did not spot call-time pass by reference. So if you're running the check in advance of upgrading php to 5.4, you either need to install 5.4 in an alternate location on the server or run the check on another server with 5.4 .

Answer (score 3):

You can't get those with regex. Use the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/tokenizer) instead. You will need to look for `'&'` where the next `'('` to the left (resolve brackets while walking there) is preceded by `T_STRING` but not by `T_FUNCTION`.

```
$tokens = new TokenStream($source);
foreach ($tokens as $i => $token) {
    if ($token->is(T_AMP)) {
        while ($i--) {
            if ($tokens[$i]->is(T_CLOSE_ROUND, T_CLOSE_SQUARE, T_CLOSE_CURLY)) {
                $i = $tokens->complementaryBracket($i);
            } elseif ($tokens[$i]->is(T_OPEN_ROUND)) {
                if ((($tokens[--$i]->is(T_WHITESPACE) && $tokens[--$i]->is(T_STRING))
                     || $tokens[$i]->is(T_STRING))
                    && !$tokens[--$i]->is(T_WHITESPACE)
                    && !$tokens[--$i]->is(T_FUNCTION)
                ) {
                    throw new Exception('Call-time pass by reference');
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This utilizes [my TokenStream wrapper](http://github.com/nikic/tokenstream). With the native output it will get quite a bit harder ;)

Comment: If utilizing negative lookahead assertions, I think it might be possible. If no one can give a reasonable regexp, tokenization just might win :-(

Comment: @ircmaxell: If the `'('` is preceded by `T_STRING` it cannot be preceded by `T_ARRAY` ;)

Comment: @Kenaniah: The problem is that you will need to resolve recursive brackets, strings and loads of other language constructs. This can't be done by regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!^.*(function|foreach|array)).*\(.*\&\$.*\)
```

This should help.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Works wonders thank you. an explanation would have been apriciated but not really nessasary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
/(->|::|call_user_func|call_user_func_callable).*\(.*\&\$/
```

It will match the following strings:

```
'->($arg1, &$arg2)'
'->(&$arg1, $arg2)'
'::($arg1, &$arg2)'
'::(&$arg1, $arg2)'
'call_user_func($callback, &$arg2)'
'$callback, &$arg2)'
'call_user_func_callable $callback, &$param_arr)'
```

In case of `call_user_func_callable` it is not necessary to check if the parameter array holds references. Passing references within an array is not considered call time pass by reference and totally fine.